# Is it possible to send blob from client to server via Actioncable for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blob, actioncable

I have searched everywhere for this and haven't come across anyone else with this issue: I am unable to send a blob over a web socket using Actioncable. For whatever reason the channel always receives that data as an empty object. Here is the related code.

A blob:

```
var blob = new Blob(['something'], {type: 'text/plain'});
```

Active cable subscription js:

```
App.messageChannel = App.cable.subscriptions.create(
  {
    channel: "MessageChannel",
    id: some_id
  },
  {
    received: function(data) {
      return console.log("The data is " + data);
    },
  },
);

App.messageChannel.send(blob);
```

I try to send that from the client to the server and it does send via websocket successfully, but it just sends back `data: "{}"`. It doesn't actually send the blob data. Interestingly if I inspect the network web socket requests, it shows an empty object as being sent (so I don't believe the server is receiving the blob, even though it's being created in the script).

Any ideas? Does ActionCable only support JSON data or am I missing some other obvious element?